# Passing function as argument with template return value

Tags: c++, templates

I have some c++ function that looks like follows:

```
template<class T> bool function(QString *text, T number, T (*f)(QString, bool)){
    bool ok = true;
    QString c = "hello";
    T col = (*f)(c, &ok);
    // do something with col here ...
    return true;
 }
```

I am calling it from outside in following manner

```
double num = 0.45;
double (*fn)(QString, bool) = &doubleFromString;
function(&text, num, fn);
```

and (Edited)

```
unsigned int num = 5;
int (*fn)(QString, bool) = &intFromString;
function(&text, num, fn);
```

And I get error

```
template parameter T is ambigious
```

I guess that problem is in combining template and passing function as argument, but I am not sure how to figure that out. (I don't want to write the function twice just with different types). Any solution?

Comment: I replaced `QString` with `std::string`, which shouldn't make a difference, and I [can't reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f18cb5b956581425) it.

Comment: I can't reproduce this either, but you could override template argument deduction by calling `function<double>(&text, num, fn)`

Comment: In your (edited) example, the `number` argument is an `unsigned int`, while your function pointer returns `int`. Those aren't the same types, hence the compiler error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message indicates that the template argument for `T` is deduced inconsistently - i.e. the returned type of `fn` and the type of `num` differ in your second code snippet.

This can be solved in several ways, of which the following one is perhaps the simplest:

```
template<class T, class R>
bool function(QString *text, T number, R (*f)(QString, bool)) {
    // [..]
    T col = f(c, &ok); // Cast if necessary. Dereferencing is superfluous, btw.
    // [..]
    return true;
 }
```

Or, even simpler than that,

```
template<class T, class F>
bool function(QString *text, T number, F f) {
    bool ok = true;
    QString c = "hello";
    T col = f(c, &ok);
    // [..]
    return true;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, that was really the problem .. I just forgot to copy the second call of function, where is type mismatch (unsigned int and int). See my edits